# 'report_activate_error' when running 'pod update' from command line

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods

I am getting a 'report_activate_error' when running 'pod update' from command line.
Specifically"

```
$ pod update

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:777:
in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem json (>= 1.7.7, ~> 1.7) (Gem::LoadError)
```

This was after updating everything I could following one error to another. In particular after installing updates to macports (specifically rvm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to to uninstall and reinstall cocoapods after the updating and all is working again.

```
$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```